# React Native WebView And Local Html Issue

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, commonjs, es6-modules

So, basically, i'm experimenting with React Native and i have imported a local file with react native's `WebView`. It works! Within the local file, i have a javascript script which creates a canvas element.

Now, I need the javascript script from the local html and the `app.js` component to communicate to eachother to change variables and such. I've tried creating a middle man javascript file which contains all static variables for the `app.js` component to change aswell as the javascript script from the html.
 But since I'm implementing the middle man javascript file in the `index.html`, I doesn't like it when I add export in the middle man js.

Here are my pictures of my files.

[image]

[image]

[image]